# React Native: Unmounting WebViews in ListView

Tags: android, webview, youtube, react-native

I use webviews to display youtube videos in a list view. Using react-native-youtube is not possible since it can't display multiple videos in the same component due an API limitation in android. The problem with webviews is that the video keeps playing if not paused even after navigating away from the component or scrolling down. How can I unmount the component once the webview is out of the screen?

Comment: Have you find any answer?